# Webdriver won't find all IE 11 windows?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriverJS (via node) to do some automated testing.  I have a test I'm trying to write to work on multiple browsers, and it works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but in IE (version 11, 32-bit), I keep having the consistent problem where I can't switch to other windows besides the main one.

Basically, as part of the test I'll have it click a button that opens up a link in a new window, then I attempt to switch to that window and continue.  Getting all the window handles and then using switchTo() to switch has worked fine in the other browsers, but not IE.  Using the same method gets me the error:

`UnknownError: null value in entry: name=null
  ...
 ==== async task ====
 WebDriver.switchTo().window(undefined)`

So I ran:

`driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
    console.log(handles.length)
 });`

to see if the windows were appearing.  And every time, the result has been 1, being only the main window.  I can see the new windows that have been opened, but webdriver can't for whatever reason.  Is there anything more I need to do to get these windows to be visible to the driver?  Any sort of workaround?

I know that IE requires some settings to work properly with Selenium.  My protected mode settings are fine, and I've done the FEATURE_BFCACHE key in the registry.  It just seems to be unable to find any new windows.

Using IE 11 with the 32-bit driver, and Windows 7 64-bit.  Again, my language is javascript.  Let me know if there is more info you need to answer.

Comment: when I actually try to switch to a new window, I get UnknownError: null value in entry: name=null, because it's trying to switch to a handle that doesn't exist.  I know there are multiple windows, but the driver doesn't seem to know that.

Comment: And, what magic are you doing inside the function(handles)?

Comment: normally switching to the second one, as there should only be the main and the popup.  Specifically: 
`driver.switchTo().window(handles[1])`

Comment: @Metlwing Did you find any workaround for this issue. Even I'm facing the same problem.